# "Готов ли ответ?": помощь в решении задачи

Tags: python

```
– Готов ли ответ, вы хотите спросить? – величаво перебил компьютер. – Да.
– Ответ на Великий Вопрос Жизни, Вселенной и Всего Остального?
– Да.
– И ты можешь сообщить его нам?
– Да.
– Прямо сейчас?
– Прямо сейчас. – Хотя я не думаю, что он вам понравится.
– Не важно! Мы должны знать! Немедленно!
– Ответ на Великий Вопрос…
– Ну!
– Жизни, Вселенной и Всего Остального…
– Ну!
– Это… – произнес компьютер и замолчал.
– Ну!
– Сорок два, – с бесконечным спокойствием сообщил компьютер.
```

Напишите программу, которая выбирает наиболее подходящий ответ.

Формат ввода
Вводятся строки слов через дефис, пока не будет введена строка 42.

Формат вывода
Из каждой строки без повторений выбрать слова, в которых есть первая буква последнего слова этой строки (независимо от регистра). Слова упорядочить по алфавиту и вывести через пробел. Если длина полученной строки кратна ее номеру (счет с 1), то все слова выводить с прописной буквы, остальные строчные.

Пример 1
Ввод

```
Is-the-answer-ready-you-want-to-ask
the-computer-interrupted-grandly
Yes
42
```

Вывод

```
Answer Ask Ready Want
grandly
Yes
```

Пример 2
Ввод

```
The-Answer-to-the-Great-Question
Well
Life-the-Universe-and-Everything-Else
Well
This-is-the-computer-said-and-then-stopped
Well
42
```

Вывод

```
Question
Well
Else Everything Life Universe The
Well
This Is Said Stopped
Well
```

Сделал решение но не могу понять в чём проблема

```
a = input()
s = []
s2 = []
n = 1
bool = 0
while a != "42":
    if len(a) % n == 0:
        bool = 1
    a = a.split("-")
    for i in a:
        if a[-1][0].lower() in i.lower():
            s.append(i)
    if bool:
        for j in sorted(s):
            s2.append(j.capitalize())
        print(*s2)
    else:
        print(*sorted(s))
    a = input()
    s = []
    n += 1
    s2 = []
    bool = 0
```

Comment: Вы не написали - а в чём собственно проблема? Она вообще есть?

Comment: Сходу я вижу только что вы назвали переменную встроенным типом питона `bool`, так делать не надо.

Comment: А так что-то у вас с условиями задачи не то, мне кажется, надо бы чётче сформулировать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как вариант:

```
res = []

index = 0
while True:

    text = input()
    if text == "42":
        break

    index += 1

    words = [word.lower() for word in text.split("-")]

    words_selected = set(word for word in words if words[-1][0] in word)

    words_sorted = sorted(list(words_selected))

    string = ' '.join(words_sorted)

    if len(string) % index == 0:
        string = ' '.join([word.title() for word in words_sorted])

    res.append(string)

print(*res, sep='\n')
```

можно избавиться от `index` как лишней сущности:

```
res = []

while True:

    text = input()
    if text == "42":
        break

    words = [word for word in text.split("-")]

    words_selected = set(word for word in words if words[-1].lower()[0] in word.lower())

    words_sorted = sorted(list(words_selected))

    string = ' '.join(words_sorted)

    if len(string) % (len(res) + 1) == 0:
        string = ' '.join([word.title() for word in words_sorted])

    res.append(string)

print(*res, sep='\n')
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но когда вводится
The-Answer-to-the-Great-Question
Well
Life-the-Universe-and-Everything-Else
Well
This-is-the-computer-said-and-then-stopped
Well
42

Выводит
Question
Well
Else Everything Life The Universe
Well
Is Said Stopped This
well

А должно
Question
Well
Else Everything Life Universe The
Well
This Is Said Stopped
Well

Comment: исправил второй свой код (в первом можно схожие изменения сделать) - связаны с тем, чтобы не переводить слова вначале в нижний регистр - этого не требуется, а вот сравнивать с нижним регистром надо:     `words = [word for word in text.split("-")]     words_selected = set(word for word in words if words[-1].lower()[0] in word.lower())`

Answer (score 1):

Немного поправил ваш код и для наглядности заменил `input` на список:

```
a = ['Is-the-answer-ready-you-want-to-ask',
     'the-computer-interrupted-grandly-the',
     'Yes-Yes',
     '42']


for j,l in enumerate(a,1):
    if l=='42': break
    s = set()
    b = l.split("-")
    for i in b:
        if b[-1][0].lower() in i.lower():
            s.add(i)
    s = ' '.join(sorted(s))
    if len(s)%j==0:
        s = s.title()
    print(s)
```

У вас код не сработал потому, что проверяете кратность длины исходной строки, а по условию надо проверять готовую строку. Также, по условию в готовых строках не должно быть повторений слов, у вас в коде нет такой проверки.

Результат:

```
'''
Answer Ask Ready Want
Computer Interrupted The
Yes
```